# Why does destructoring works with events, and wont work without it

Tags: reactjs, events, destructuring

when I use this code :

```
 onChange = e => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
     this.setState(currentState => ({
      tempInput: { ...currentState.tempInput, [name]: value }
    }));
  };
```

everything works fine, but when I do this:

```
 onChange = e => {
     this.setState(currentState => ({
      tempInput: { ...currentState.tempInput, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }
    }));
  };
```

I get an error : TypeError: e.target is null,
what is the difference? am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `this.setState()` is `asynchronous`. So `e` becomes undefined when it gets executed.

To mitigate it, you can destruct `e` in the `onChange` function parameters, which keeps `name` and `value` defined within the onChange functional scope:

```
 onChange = ({ target: { value, name } }) => {
     this.setState(currentState => ({
      tempInput: { ...currentState.tempInput, [name]: value }
    }));
  };
```

Or... you can can destruct `e.target` before executing `this.setState()`, which also keeps `name` and `value` defined within the `onChange` functional scope:

```
 onChange = e => {
     const { name, value } = e.target;
     this.setState(currentState => ({
      tempInput: { ...currentState.tempInput, [name]: value }
    }));
  };
```

Comment: thank you! but if the example is asynchronous, why does destructoring works? it gets the value faster or something? why is it defining in it in the scope? I would very much like to know.!

Comment: You destruct BEFORE executing `this.setState()`. It's like stating `var name = e.target.name` within the function. Now, you can utilize `name` anywhere within the function's scope. Anything outside of `onChange` has no awareness of `name` because it's scoped to the `onChange` function from where it was declared: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: so basically when I destructor it , it forces the value to be updated, and when I don't it can be updated whenever and so that's why It gets null? is that it?

Comment: It doesn't "force" the value. It declares the value. Then that declared value can be utilized anywhere within the function's scope. See link above for local versus global scope.

Comment: The bit you are missing: React reuses event objects.  So if you don't synchronously capture the values you need from the event object, you will run into trouble.  Your asynchronous setState callback is running after React has had time to modify the ev object for some other purpose.